# authentication for restapi which shared by multiple webapps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, restful-authentication

I have 3 wars: `a.war`, `b.war` and `restful.war`, they are in the same tomcat.

`restful.war` is a spring boot, spring mvc project, it provides restful call for `a.war` and `b.war`.

`a.war` and `b.war` are independent webapps, they all have their own login system, their users are stored in different database tables, e.g. the users of `a.war` are stored in `tableA`, the users of `b.war` are stored in `tableB`.

for `a.war` and `b.war`, there are two places to call `restful.war`:

1. call code of `restful.war` from java code in `a.war`, `b.war` via `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute()`
2. call `restful.war` from html/jsp page of `a.war`,`b.war` via ajax

what I want is : only the user who login `a.war` or `b.war` can call `restful.war`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement basic authentication in 'restful'  application and call its endpoint from 'a'  and 'b' with proper "Authorization" header.  **So this will solve problem where if 'restful' gets a call from 'a' or  'b'  it will respond or else it will throw 403 forbidden error.**

Comment: thanks for your answer.do you mean use username and password to do basic authentication? if yes, then 1. what if I have no https? 2. what about its security when using basic authentication with https?

Comment: and 3. because `a.war` and `b.war` use different user tables, so if using basic authc with username and password, then `restful.war` need to know the request is from `a` or `b`, such that it can check corresponding user table, right?

Comment: Point 1 and 2 is not an issue you can have basic auth in http/https.

Comment: I mean to create separate auth mechanism in restful.war. Then use that user / password (this user is not same as the one you use in 'a' and 'b'. its maintained spearately in 'restful')from 'a' and 'b' to get authenticated.

Comment: You should be having some auth(basic or token based) mechanism in 'restful' application. Only 'a' and 'b' application are going to call with proper credentials. Any call from other places without credentials will be denied.

Comment: i have code like `jquery.ajax()` in `jsp/html` of `a.war` to call `restful.war`, if using basic auth in `restful.war`, then I have to add username/password in `jsp/html` of `a.war` like `jquery.ajax(beforeSend: function (req) {req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);})`, right? if yes, then doesn't it anyone can see the `auth info` from the page? e.g. from the web developer tool of firefox.

Comment: You can move this  call to server side service of 'a' or ' b' and just call that service to get info from your client side. You basic auth or  token auth is up to your application complexity. Anyway you need some kind of auth mechanism in 'restful'.

Comment: i cannot move this call to server side, because there are a lot of this call in many `jsp/html` pages. so in this case, basic auth is not suite for me, right? and what other mechanism is good for me?

Comment: If your 'restful' url value in all jsp's of applications ('a' or 'b') is taken from global constant then simply point it to your service in server side. Keep the 'restful'  call in the server side.